# desktop multi window flutter package

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, dart, multi-window

I am using [desktop multi window package](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window). I am able to display or show any UI on the secondary (multi) window which this package supports in flutter out of the box.

I am facing issues while trying to show/play videos on secondary screen (multi window). I am getting

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException